# how to xml format string parsing data in android studio in java

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, xml-parsing

I am trying in this code

```
String DeviceInfo= 
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><DeviceInfo dc="" dpId="" mc="" mi="" rdsId="" rdsVer=""/>"
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    { super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); if (resultCode ==
            RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle b = data.getExtras();
        if (b != null) {
            String deviceInfo = b.getString("DEVICE_INFO", "");
            String pidData = b.getString("PID_DATA");

            String dnc = b.getString("DNC", "");

            String dnr = b.getString("DNR", "");

            // String deviceinfo = bundle.getString("DEVICE_INFO");
            Log.d("device ",""+deviceInfo);
            String rdServiceInfo = b.getString("RD_SERVICE_INFO", "");


        /*  *//*  if
            (!dnc.isEmpty() || !dnr.isEmpty())
            { showLogInfoDialog("Device Info", dnc + dnr + " " +
                    deviceInfo + rdServiceInfo);
            }
          {
                //showLogInfoDialog("Device Info","" +deviceInfo );
            }*//*
            try {
                DocumentBuilderFactory dbf =
                        DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
                InputSource is = new InputSource();
                is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(deviceInfo));

                Document doc = db.parse(is);
                NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("employee");

                // iterate the employees
                for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
                    Element element = (Element) nodes.item(i);

                    NodeList name = element.getElementsByTagName("value");
                    Element line = (Element) name.item(0);
                    System.out.println("value: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));

                    NodeList title = element.getElementsByTagName("title");
                    line = (Element) title.item(0);
                    System.out.println("Title: " + getCharacterDataFromElement(line));
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }*/







             text1.setText(pidData);
            text.setText(deviceInfo);

        } } }
```

in this  xml format string

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

What i understood from you question is you need to know how to parse String xml data. And then map the values to the respective fields. So below is the sample method which will parse the xml from string and gives the elements one by one.

```
/**
 * 
 * @param inputXmlS is String xml Data 
 */
public void xmlParser(String inputXmlS){
    try {
        XmlPullParserFactory xmlFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        xmlFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        XmlPullParser xmlPullParser = xmlFactory.newPullParser();
        xmlPullParser.setInput(new StringReader(inputXmlS));
        int event = xmlPullParser.getEventType();
        while (event != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if(event == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Start document");
            } else if(event == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Start tag "+xmlPullParser.getName());
            } else if(event == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                Log.d(TAG,"End tag "+xmlPullParser.getName());
            } else if(event == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
                Log.d(TAG,"Text "+xmlPullParser.getText());
            }
            event = xmlPullParser.next();
        }
        Log.d(TAG,"End document");

    } catch (XmlPullParserException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

So now you can call this method like below

```
String deviceInfo= "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><DeviceInfo dc="" dpId="" mc="" mi="" rdsId="" rdsVer=""/>";
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{ super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); if (resultCode ==
        RESULT_OK) {
 xmlParser(deviceInfo);
 }
}
```

Thats it.